# RecyclerView in ViewPager not Updating, working fine in Code, but not in Device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I had a severe problem and have not been able to solve it for the last three days, I'm explaining an issue here so you call help me out (and yes, before asking question here, I have already done R&D over the internet, have checked many different SO question and GitHub issues as well, after not being able to solve an issue, finally Now I'm asking a question).

I'm working on a Quiz app, where I have an activity with `ViewPager` for showing questions and options along with other views. In ViewPager, I have `RecyclerView` to show options within ViewPager.

Here's a UI for the same with some of the code blocks:
[image]

Now the functionality is if I have an option selected, then if I click on the `Clear` button, the selection should be removed, which I have done already, but the issue is when I click the `Clear` button, I'm getting debug point in the last `else` condition, where it should go where I'm removing selection for the item(applying `normalBackGround` variable), according to the code it's working as I'm getting debug point at the correct point, but in the device, the selection is not getting removed.

Here, a few days ago, I was using `ViewPager2` along with `FragmentStateAdapter`, but due to some different issues I have replaced it with `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and those issues are now resolved, but this one is still the same, option is not updating.

I'm adding links to my code/classes for the references below:

`QuestionActivity.kt` - https://pastebin.com/msbmVMjA

`QuestionsViewPagerAdapter.kt` - https://pastebin.com/habMbd8W

`QuestionsItemFragment.kt` - https://pastebin.com/wZsVuMex

`QuestionViewAdapter.kt` - https://pastebin.com/iEKQ0ity

Any help will be appreciated and let me know if I can improve my question anyhow, Thank You!

Comment: I managed it by applying different logic according to my task and flow/steps, but still, I'll wait for an answer if anyone has faced this kind of issue or knows the solution.